# Why doesn't my Alert Dialog Work inside a Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, handler, progressdialog

I'm using a thread so that I can show a progress dialog while my app loads some data. If there is an error it will stop the progress dialog and show the popup saying "error". However I found out that alert dialogs cannot run inside a UI thread and that I need to use a Handler. Can someone with help with this issue? Here is my code. Thanks

```
verifyCode.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(
          Activate.this, "", "Loading...");    

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
               try {
                     new AlertDialog.Builder(Activate.this)
                    .setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.InvalidKey))
                    .setMessage(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.PleaseEntervalidRegistration)).setNeutralButton(
                    "OK", null).show();

                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    //more code
     }).start();
}
```

Comment: Uh..may I ask why a new thread is neccessary? Because it looks like the whole execution is synchronous. Also, as best practice, always try to avoid handling threads directly. Android has a class called AsyncTask to handle asynchronous execution.

Comment: The reason I am putting in a thread is because I wanted to add in the progress dialog. All of the examples I have seen have the progress dialog finish within a thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make changes to UI element on non-UI threads. `onClick` will run on the UI thread, but since you spawn a `Thread` inside `onClick` then non-UI elements cannot be manipulated from inside that `Thread`. Move your `AlertDialog` and `ProgressDialog` calls to just prior to spawning the new `Thread`.

Also, as @lightblade suggested, If you need to do some sort of action which requires heavy background processing and UI manipulation based on that processing, then you should use `AsyncTask`s. It provides methods you can override for pre-processing, actual processing, post-processing, and updating progress.

Comment: I tried to call my progress dialog without using the thread and the progress dialog didn't show up at all. I'm a little bit confused on how to use AsyncTask, Could you help modify some of my code so that I see what I need to replace for this to work properly? Thanks